# What's the situation with Baen's Bar?

Tags: fandom, conventions, baen

Apparently, Baen's Bar, a popular and long-running "virtual convention" for sci-fi aficionados, [is being put on hiatus](https://www.baen.com/bb021621):

> That said, it has come to our attention that allegations about the Bar have been made elsewhere. We take these allegations seriously, and consequently have put the Bar on hiatus while we investigate. But we will not commit censorship of lawful speech.

Anyone know what is going on?

Comment: Per the FAQ, questions about fandom are firmly on-topic.

Comment: Meta post discussing the question: [Are questions about SF/F fan forums on-topic?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13272/31394)

Answer (score 16):

Per [this post](https://www.patreon.com/posts/baen-books-forum-47582408), the site was accused of being used to "*advocate for extremist political violence*" by [certain individuals](https://twitter.com/jasonsanford/status/1361816082261098496).

> Since the November 3rd elections, Baen’s Bar has seen a surge of new
> registrants.[See Note 6]  While most of these new members have not yet
> posted anything, some of these users appeared to join the forum
> because other platforms they used, such as Parler and now-banned
> Reddits, had been shut down.
>
> ...
>
> ...Baen’s Bar, the private forum run by the science fiction and fantasy publishing company Baen Books, is being used to advocate for extremist political violence.

I would imagine that Baen has closed their forum due to the usual threats of "*cancellation*" (e.g. de-monetisation and loss of their hosting/technology/publishing partners).

You might also want to note that several of their partner authors have ['clapped back' at the original allegations](https://ericflint.net/information/controversy-about-baens-bar/), pointing out that they're atypical of the site and its users and are selectively (possibly even deceptively) chosen

Comment: According to the [notice at bar.baen.com](https://bar.baen.com), the closure is (at least at present) temporary. If the closure does in fact become permanent, then the cancellers will have won, even if Baen had not actually been threatened with loss of hosting/connectivity/funding.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin - A very quick look at the Twitter link above would suggest that copies of the offending conversations have been forwarded to Baen's hosts, partners and authors in a clear attempt to leverage as much outrage as possible.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't look at that tweet; I'm not a twit at all, and I can almost guarantee that even if I were, I would not be one of the poster's 'elect'. All I can see is the (mostly 'favorable') reactions to it.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin - Ah, he seems to have set his twitter to private.

Comment: Baen being threatened by PubIn? I wish I could say I'm surprised...

Comment: @JeffZeitlin when a *forum moderator* advocates for doxxing a police officer with the goal of having them murdered, then the "cancellers" *should* win.

Comment: The first sentence is an accurate description of Jason Sanford's post. The quote is not particularly representative of the contents of the post.

Comment: @BenCrowell - I've updated the quote to include the allegations as well as the context.

Comment: I can't say it entirely surprises me after the "Sick Puppies" situation, but it does sadden me since most of the board was not like that, but sometimes that is a consequence of a light hand in moderation.

Comment: This is why we can't have nice things.

Comment: As of 9 April 2021, the site has been reopened at a new URL and with restrictions (you must be a Baen customer, or have been active on the old site within the past year, and most of the Bar is not publicly visible). Ms Weisskopf has stated that their investigation found no illegal material.